# JS/jQuery $(document).ready() conflicting with timeout or event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, document-ready

I'm trying to build a color picker that uses rgba values from a dropdown list to change the color of an overlay.  When the value is on "pick a color", I'd like it to cycle through all of the available colors.

The following code performs exactly as I'd like it to, but I can't get it to run when the window loads.  I've tried every combination of document ready and window load imaginable.

I suspect it may be a conflicting with the timeouts or the event listener because the window alerts perfectly fine.

Here's what I'm working with:

```
var colorList = new Array();
$('#color-select option').each(function() {
    colorList.push($(this).val())
});
var colorListLength = colorList.length;
var currentColor;
var rainbowTimeout; // setTimeout variable

$("#color-select").change(function(){
    clearTimeout(rainbowTimeout);
    currentColor = $(this).val();
    if( currentColor == "pick a color"){
        rainbow();
    }else{
        $(".overlay").css("background-color",currentColor);
    }
});

var rainbowCounter = 1; // avoids "pick a color"
function rainbow(){
    $(".overlay").css("background-color",colorList[rainbowCounter]);
    rainbowCounter++;
    if( rainbowCounter == colorListLength ){
        rainbowCounter = 1; 
    }
    if(currentColor == "pick a colour"){
        rainbowTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
            rainbow();
        },1500);
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where to call rainbow() to kick start the process.  Can anyone tell me what might be causing the problem?

Comment: I don't see the $(document).ready() function anywhere in your code?

Comment: Thank you for replying.  I'm not sure where to place it.  It doesn't work anywhere that I've tried.  Can you suggest somewhere that might work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see a `$(document).ready()` anywhere in your code. So if you are asking how to execute the code you've shown on page load, you probably want something like this,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var colorList = new Array();
    $('#color-select option').each(function() {
        colorList.push($(this).val())
    });
    var colorListLength = colorList.length;
    var currentColor;
    var rainbowTimeout; // setTimeout variable

    $("#color-select").change(function(){
        clearTimeout(rainbowTimeout);
        currentColor = $(this).val();
        if( currentColor == "pick a color"){
            rainbow();
        }else{
            $(".overlay").css("background-color",currentColor);
        }
    });

    var rainbowCounter = 1; // avoids "pick a color"
    function rainbow(){
        $(".overlay").css("background-color",colorList[rainbowCounter]);
        rainbowCounter++;
        if( rainbowCounter == colorListLength ){
            rainbowCounter = 1; 
        }
        if(currentColor == "pick a colour"){
            rainbowTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
                rainbow();
            },1500);
        }
    }

    rainbow();
});
```

Based on your fiddle. The problem was that your currentColor was not initialized. Doing that should get it to work,

```
var currentColor = "pick a color";
```

Comment: Naturally, I tried this before posting.  I would expect this to work, but that is where my confusion begins.  With this code, the rainbow function only starts after I change the select box off and back onto "pick a color".

Comment: you need to initialize your 'currentColor' var (updated answer with that)

Comment: Oh wow.  I definitely feel a little silly.  I just started coding a few months ago so I'll play my rookie card ;)

I really appreciate your help.